# Use cached response only. Without network call

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

There is an API that has calls limit, in this case I want to cache response and don't run network response if cache is still valid.

First of all I have `cache interceptor`

```
fun provideCacheInterceptor(): Interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .maxStale(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .onlyIfCached()
                .build()
        response.newBuilder()
                .header("CacheControl", cacheControl.toString())
                .build()
    }
```

I attach cache and interceptor to the client

```
client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(cacheInterceptor)
```

As I result when I'm trying to check if the reponse from cache and/or from network

```
Log.e("!@#", "cached: ${it.raw().cacheResponse()?.toString()}")
Log.e("!@#", "network: ${it.raw().networkResponse()?.toString()}")
```

I get

```
cached: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=, url=https://API}
network: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://API}
```

Is there any way ***not*** to call the network endpoint if cache is still valid?

Comment: Can you post the implementation/stub of the `loggingInterceptor`?

Comment: Ideally if you don't call `chain.proceed(chain.request());` network call should not happen.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao loggin interceptor is a library HttpLoggingInterceptor. I don't think it's a good idea to break the chain inside interceptor because there could be several other interceptors that are not ready to miss requests.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'cacheInterceptor '. Is `cacheInterceptor` also a library or your own implementation?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao cache interceptor implementation was in question already. I've found the issue, thank you, you could check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in my implementation that I proceed the original request and apply header to response (my bad), need to modify initial request and proceed modified request then.
Also seems like `Cache-Control` header typo.

The proper cache interceptor looks like

```
fun provideCacheInterceptor(networkManager: NetworkManager): Interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request()
        val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .maxStale(6, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build()
        chain.proceed(request.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
                .build())
    }
```